# Windows 2012 Server DHCP ignores reservations

Tags: windows, dhcp, dhcp-server

**Given** a Windows 2012 Server DHCP server

**When** a add an IP Reservation for an IP address providing the client's MAC address

**And** this client is powered off

**And** a different Windows client with a different MAC address requests this IP address

**Then** the new client will get the IP address despite MAC mismatch

**And** the reservation will be renamed to the new clients FQDN.

How is that then a reservation!?

Comment: DHCP clients should not be dictating to the DHCP server which IP address they want. Like you said below, you don't even see a DHCPDISCOVER. If you are trying to prove a hypothetical, that's fine, but the process is: 1) client asks for an available IP 2) Server suggests an IP 3) client accepts. In which case the server will never suggest a reserved IP address. Please update your question and specify how you have forced your computers to "steal" an IP.

Answer (score 0):

When an IP addressed is reserved by MAC address the server will *not* offer it to some other client, whether it specifically requests it or not.

Do you use multiple scopes? These must not overlap.

Multiple DHCP servers? Are they synchronized?

Comment: One server, one scope. Bewilderingly, Wireshark shows that sometimes there's neither DHCPDISCOVER nor DHCPOFFER, only DHCPREQUEST and DHCPACK.

Comment: At 50% of lease duration a Windows client will attempt to renew it's lease without going through the full DORA process. See figure 4.3 in this article  sections. https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc958935.aspx also check the renewing and rebinding sections for further useful info

Answer (score 0):

> Then the new client will get the IP address despite MAC mismatch

DHCP does not *deny* a IP address to a client; longer lease times or manual configuration ognore reservations. A reservation *only* kicks in when the client is reuqesting a address.

> And the reservation will be renamed to the new clients FQDN.

Yes, thats the default behaviour. For any IP address - the 'name' field is dynamically filled by the client.

Answer (score 0):

> And a different Windows client with a different MAC address requests
>   this IP address

You are 100% sure that other computer is not in static mode or does not have that IP as a secondary IP ? I ask as you don't even see the DHCP message in wireshark.